# How to use cut command for multple files and paste the result in different file

Tags: linux, cut

Could you please help me how to cut multiple field in multiple file and paste the results in  another file

```
       file1:
       A Pass Fail
       B Pass Fail
       C Fail Fail
       D Pass Pass

      file2:
      A Pass Pass
      B Fail Pass
      C Pass Pass
      D Pass Pass

      file 3:
      A  Fail Fail
      B  Pass Pass
      C  Pass Fail
      D  Pass Pass

    Expected:
    A Pass Fail Pass Pass Fail Fail
    B Pass Fail Fail Pass Pass Pass
    C Fail Fail Pass Pass Pass Fail
    D Pass Pass Pass Pass Pass Pass
```

I have tried below option and it is not working
cut -f 2-3 file2 | cut -f 2-3 file3 | paste file1 -

Answer (score 1):

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | tr "\t" " " | cut -f1,2,3,5,6,8,9 -d" "
```

This will result to:

```
A Pass Fail Pass Pass Fail Fail
B Pass Fail Fail Pass Pass Pass
C Fail Fail Pass Pass Pass Fail
D Pass Pass Pass Pass Pass Pass
```

Short explanation:

`paste file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` will combine your files tab separated.

```
A Pass Fail     A Pass Pass     A Fail Fail
B Pass Fail     B Fail Pass     B Pass Pass
C Fail Fail     C Pass Pass     C Pass Fail
D Pass Pass     D Pass Pass     D Pass Pass
```

`tr "\t" " "` to replace the tab to space. Then `cut -f1,2,3,5,6,8,9 -d" "` will get the columns you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Awk alternative:

```
awk '{ map[$1]=map[$1]" "$0 } END { for (i in map) { gsub(" "i,"",map[i]);print i" "map[i] } }' file1 file2 file3
```

Create an array called map with the first space delimited field as the index and appending the lines of each file separated by a space as the value. At the end of processing the files, loop through the map array, removing the indexes from the values using gsub and then printing the resulting values.